# how to extract two characters from a string in javascript

Tags: regex

I tried to extract 'US' from the following string, but it returns null, any idea? Thanks

```
console.log('sample sample 1234 (US)'.match(/\(W{2}\)$/))
```

Comment: It should be `\w{2}` or better `[A-Z]{2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`W` matches a letter `W`. It should be `\w{2}` or better `[A-Z]{2}`. Capture it with `(...)` and access the 1st captured value:

```js
console.log('sample sample 1234 (US)'.match(/\(([A-Z]{2})\)$/)[1]);
// Or, with error checking
let m = 'sample sample 1234 (US)'.match(/\(([A-Z]{2})\)$/);
let res = m ? m[1] : "";
console.log(res)
```

If you do not want to access the contents of the capturing group, you need to post-process the results of `/\([A-Z]{2}\)$/` regex:

```js
let m = 'sample sample 1234 (US)'.match(/\([A-Z]{2}\)$/);
let res = m[0].substring(1, m[0].length-1) || "";
console.log(res);
```

Comment: thanks, two approaches all works, it returns '(US)', if I want only the 'US'?

Comment: What do you mean by "it returns `(US)`"? See the console output. I added a third approach, please be specific.

Comment: i meant if I can get only 'US' without parentheses

Comment: All my "3" (actually, 2) approaches get you the `US` without parentheses. Show *all* relevant code to see if you have other issues there.